# Selenium2 WebDriver release notes

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, release-notes

I've been looking around to find the release notes for the latest releases but I couldn't find it.  Anyone have a link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different parts of the project have different logs of the changes between versions. The most comprehensive changelog for the project is the one for the Java language bindings, and it can be found [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/java/CHANGELOG). Other portions of the project may have their own changelogs, but they are usually limited to changes only within that part of the project. Examples include the changelogs for the [.NET language bindings](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/dotnet/CHANGELOG) and for the [IE driver standalone server](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/cpp/iedriverserver/CHANGELOG).